# Android does not show permission dialog for RECORD_AUDIO in android 6.0

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Android does not show permission dialog for RECORD_AUDIO

I have added the required permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

and following code

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
 Toast.makeText(this, "RECORD AUDIO Permission is required.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
```

and to check it

```
if (!checkPermission()) {
                requestPermission();
            }
```

however the dialog to ask permission or the screen asking for permission is not shown ,

I am testing on android 6.0 on an emulator

Comment: please show your gradle file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method only signals if a message should be shown. You should request permission regardless of its return value.

Take a look at line 142 in this sample: https://developer.android.com/samples/RuntimePermissions/src/com.example.android.system.runtimepermissions/MainActivity.html#l142

> ```
> /**
>  * Requests the Camera permission.
>  * If the permission has been denied previously, a SnackBar will prompt the user to grant the
>  * permission, otherwise it is requested directly.
>  */
> private void requestCameraPermission() {
>     Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");
>
>     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
>             Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
>         // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
>         // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
>         // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
>         Log.i(TAG,
>                 "Displaying camera permission rationale to provide additional context.");
>         Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
>                 Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
>                 .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onClick(View view) {
>                         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
>                                 new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
>                                 REQUEST_CAMERA);
>                     }
>                 })
>                 .show();
>     } else {
>
>         // Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
>         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
>                 REQUEST_CAMERA);
>     }
> }
> ```