# Voice interaction service blocks record audio permission

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition

I am making an app which use google assit api, speech recognition and the voice interaction service .. everythings seems to work fine but the problems comes when my app is set as the default assistance app .. when i do so the speech recognition stops working  as if the record audio permission were not granted but it is cheked in settings..

Does anybody has any idea of what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details of your .xml or java code for exact situation analysis. From your limited information , it looks like users need to grant Google App's RECORD_AUDIO permission. If it's the case, refer to these post:

[(Android Studio Speech Recognizer) I'm getting error 9 (insufficient Privileges) even though I have given it RECORD_AUDIO and INTERNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891491/android-studio-speech-recognizer-im-getting-error-9-insufficient-privileges?rq=1)

[Android does not show permission dialog for RECORD_AUDIO in android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947466/android-does-not-show-permission-dialog-for-record-audio-in-android-6-0)